# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css"> not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

[Here's the Directory screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TLkQ.png)
[Here's the Directory screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WI0T.png)
I'm trying to build a Twitter clone as my first PHP project. But I'm facing this problem; the browser is not able to locate CSS file. Here's the code:

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">
    <title>Twitter</title>
</head>
```

styles.css is located in the folder one level up the current folder. Help me out!

Comment: show project structure

Comment: what's the address of your php/html file?

Comment: Open up your dev tools, check for any errors. (F12 by default for Chrome).

Comment: What server? What is the http directory entry point?  What kind of server are you running?  Any server access scripts?

Comment: I'm using xampp. Here's the directory path: C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterClone.

Comment: Twitter Clone has Folder: views and files: index.php and styles.css. Inside views, there are 3 files: header.php, footer.php, and home.php. The above html code is in header.php.

Comment: No, there ain't any errors @Luicy.

Comment: so your `style.css` is inside the folder `files`. Correct?

Comment: No, files is not a folder. I used that to indicate that those are files. This might help: TwitterClone contents: views(folder), index.php and styles.css.

Comment: can you attach an image of your directory structure? which clearly shows your files and folders of your root folder

Comment: @zainulabdeen I've attached the directory screenshot. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Everything seems fine. There might be something very silly. Which Browser Are You using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: okay! open your console to and check for errors. check what path it is taking using inspect element. To know the path expand your `head` section and hover on the path you have assigned

Comment: I got my mistake. @zainulabdeen your idea worked!. It was a silly one. I had included header.php in index.php and was trying to access index.php. But I had given path relative to header.php instead of index.php. It was a big silly mess. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use document relative links you are asking for a headache.  I always make my links root relative so

> /css/styles.css

or whatever your path relative to root is instead of

> ../styles.css

I have encountered so many errors in my career due to things being moved and document relative links.

Comment: Oh man, thanks! This worked for me. Although, I wonder what's wrong with the previous method!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Without seeing your project structure I can't tell you what was wrong with your document relative link.  Probably just off by one level or something but that is the beauty of root relative; it makes it hard to encounter errors based on incorrect resource references.